# Problem in rendering large listing in react native app

Tags: react-native

I am having problem in rendering data in my react native app.I need help. Actually there is a listing of around 3000 activities which i want to show in my app.The listing includes cards of different sizes depending on the content.I am currently using flatlist to render this dynamic content but the performance is very slow and blanks space appears after some scrolling as i scroll the listing down it gets slower. I have used the Recycler view as well but as my content cards are of dynamic sizes and recyler view limits from dynamic sizes.I really need help from experts and open to any suggestions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article would be a good starting point, it solved a lot of issues for me.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration